# Is there any way to sync on premise oracle table data to a table in Aurora postgres RDS?

Tags: postgresql, oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-migration

I've migrated a On premise Oracle to Aurora Postgres on AWS RDS. my migration process is described in the below image.

[image]

I'm looking for an option to sync data from on prem oracle to aurora postgres (Something like, if one row inserted/updated in particular table, that data should come and update/insert in aurora postgres table).

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you'll want to use the DMS (Database Migration Service) which can do continuous data replication from source to target DB's

https://aws.amazon.com/dms/

Comment: DMS is not allowed to install on Onprem Server. is there any other ways. I'm looking for options.

Comment: @aanannaphilip, Hello did u solved this problem sync data problem. We are also working on the same problem migration of on prem oracle db to Aurora postgres

Comment: aws data migration service helped !